# SiddhiQL query Error : mismatched input 'group'

Tags: group-by, mismatch, siddhi, wso2-cep

I am using a simple SiddhiQL query to get number of records having same timestamp till minute entry and these timestamps. The query is:

```
from inputStream
select time:dateFormat(ts,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') as formatedTs, count(formatedTs)
group by formatedTs
insert into outputStream;
```

It gives me the error `mismatched input 'group' expecting {'*', '+', '-', '/', '%', '<', '<=', '>', '>=', '==', '!=', AS, OR, AND, IN}`. What's wrong with `group by` clause in this context?

Comment: Can you try  `group by time:dateFormat(ts,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')`

Comment: I did but it doesn't help, getting same error

Comment: and the same with the count(time:dateFormat(ts,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')) Sorry, I am not familiar with this particular sql

Comment: If you remove the count and the group by does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Reason for the error:***

This particular error is coming due to the missing `AS`, following `count(formatedTs)`

*(This is indicated in the error message as well.
`mismatched input 'group' expecting {'*', '+', '-', '/', '%', '<',
 '<=', '>', '>=', '==', '!=', AS, OR, AND, IN}`
 Query Compiler thinks `group` is in wrong place due to the missing `AS`)*

***Correction needed:***

So the `select` statement, needs to be corrected as below:

```
select time:dateFormat(ts,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') as formatedTs, count(formatedTs) as tsCount
```

***Further correction which you might need:***

Also, does the `inputStream` has an attribute named `formatedTs`? If not, after fixing the `select` statement, you'll get another error like below:

> Cannot find attribute type as 'formatedTs' does not exist in 'inputStream'

because the attribute for which you are taking the count should exist in the `inputStream`

If that is the case, following query (which should compile successfully) might help you:

```
from inputStream
select time:dateFormat(ts,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') as formatedTs, count(ts) as countTs
group by ts
insert into outputStream;
```

### Update

Updating the query since your requirement is to group by the formatted timestamp:

```
from inputStream
select time:dateFormat(ts,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') as formatedTs
insert into innerStream;

from innerStream
select formatedTs, count(formatedTs) as countTs
group by formatedTs
insert into outStream;
```

Comment: It helped but my input stream has `seconds` in its `timestamp` i.e. `ts` and I need total number of records per `minute`, thats why I have formatted date to exclude `seconds` entry. Now if I use `ts` in `count` and `group by` clause, I wont be able to get desire results. So I use `time:dateFormat(ts,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')` in both `count` and `group by` and now it says at `group by` clause `mismatched input ':' expecting {',', HAVING, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, RETURN, OUTPUT}`. Is there any other way of what I wanna do?

Comment: I did exactly same but even than `group by` clause was causing some problems and I was given a `stream definition already exist` error. The job was done with another intermediate stream. I inserted required results in temp stream and then used select * to insert into final outputstream. Dont know why but it worked. Kindly update the edited version so I could mark answer correct.

Comment: Glad that you got it to work :) However, I'm pretty sure that the updated query compiles successfully. Did you try the exact same query? 
By the way, if you found something different which worked for you, you may post that as an answer.

Comment: Thanks your answer is correct, there is no need to post my own.